# I'm going insane.... Chrome on OSX problems

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, google-chrome, safari

OK, so this is going to drive me to drink if I spend any more time trying to figure it out.

I have a situation where things seem fine when I hit a web site from safari, but any attempt to surf *anywhere* from Chrome just hangs.  I've done a LOT to narrow this down:

- restarted laptop
- reinstalled Chrome
- tried on a network other than my
  own (in case it had something to do with my internal network setup)
- tried with a hardwired connection (in case it had something to do
  with my wifi adapter)
- I tried hitting a website on my internal network (to eliminate the internet as being related)
- I even reinstalled the OS from scratch (I don't
  use this machine for anything special so I had nothing to save)

Here is a screenshot of what Chrome looks like - at the same time, things are working fine in another window (Safari)
[image: Chrome hung]

As you can see, even the private chrome URLs hang! (e.g. chrome:settings, chrome:extensions etc). So weird!!  Eventually the Wait / kill page dialog will show up, but waiting does nothing.

What the heck am I missing?

Comment: Did you DHCP server hand out a DNS address?

Comment: Both :)  same behaviour on a wired connection